# How to change Kafka port

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Confluent Platform 7.0.1 for Ubuntu.

In version 6

[image]

but in version 7

[image]

Comment: Please use text, not images

Answer (score 0):

The `etc` folder is not the same `share/java`, so I don't know what your images are trying to show.

The answer is the same for all versions of Confluent Platform because the actual property for *Apache* Kafka didn't change.

You use `listeners` of `server.properties` to set the bind address of the server, as shown in the first image, in the `etc/` folder; and none of the Broker properties files are under `share/`

Comment: You true. When I unzip on Windows, I can see what you said. But inside Ubuntu, I use `ls -laF` , I cannot see/show what you said. This is strange I don't know how to explain.

Comment: Your images are all inside the `share/` folder, where there is no `etc/` path. You should run `ls -la ~/confluent-7.0.1/etc/kafka` instead to find your `server.properties`. Or better, `find -name server.properties ~/confluent-7.0.1`